# Package installs with lightning components failing in summer 2017 orgs

Tags: lightning-aura-components, sandbox, summer-17

We recently encountered an issue with our Managed package in Summer '17 Sandboxes, not being able to install it in them and I recently read some posts asking how to downgrade Sanboxes or why the install is failing and found out there is a known issue [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008jMrQAI&title=package-install-fails-with-error-no-controller-named-js-xxxxxx-found-or-we-couldn-t-retrieve-the-design-time-component-information-for-component) .

Would someone happen to have further details on what might actually be going on?
 (Is it safe to assume that this will be fixed rather quickly?)

Here is an excerpt of the error messages reported related to lightning components of the managed package:

> 1. No CONTROLLER named js://namespace.xxxxxx found  xxxxxxxx: No CONTROLLER named js://..... found
> 2. No HELPER named js://....... found  ......: No HELPER named js://......... found
> 3. No STYLE named css://....... found  ......: No STYLE named css://...... found
> 4. No COMPONENT named markup://...... found  ......: No COMPONENT named markup://..... found

Comment: It appears to occur because of an underlying [GACK](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gack). Other than subscribing to the known issue there won't be much more you can do. Salesforce won't typically hand out the internal error details.

Comment: Any chance that this is related to the Locker Service being enabled resulting in  breaking your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: Issue seems to be resurfacing, cf here: 
I
[Install Managed Package Into Sandbox Fails on All Lightning Component Bundles](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/230345/install-managed-package-into-sandbox-fails-on-all-lightning-component-bundles)

This probably is the known issue that has been mentioned by Daniel Ballinger, the OP, and has been reported as fixed this weekend.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008jMrQAI

> Your request to install package "Pkg Name" was unsuccessful. None of the data or setup information in your salesforce.com organization was affected.
>
> If your install continues to fail, contact Salesforce CRM Support through your normal channels and provide the following information.
>
> Organization: Org name (00D...) 
>   User: Admin User (005....) 
>   Package: Pkg name (04t.....) 
>   Error Number: 738622687-150264 (415018139) --->this varies 
>   Problem:
>
> 1. No CONTROLLER named js://namespace.xxxxxx found 
>      xxxxxxxx: No CONTROLLER named js://..... found
> 2. No HELPER named js://....... found 
>      ......: No HELPER named js://......... found
> 3. No STYLE named css://....... found 
>      ......: No STYLE named css://...... found
> 4. No COMPONENT named markup://...... found 
>      ......: No COMPONENT named markup://..... found

The other failing error message mentioned in the issue is interesting, too.

Edit: I could not reproduce the first error (No Controller...) but I could reproduce the other one mentioned even after the fix by using faulty access attributes on cmps living on a FlexiPage.

Comment: Looks like this issue is actual again, we are getting 'No CONTROLLER, No HELPER, No ...' error now when trying to install our managed package. Really strange cause I was able to install successfully same package version just yesterday, but cannot do it today anymore. Reaching to SF support for help)

Comment: Check this out: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/230345/install-managed-package-into-sandbox-fails-on-all-lightning-component-bundles