# No COMPONENT named markup://ui_popover:popover found

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

1. Installed [Lightning Popover](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EOJPHUA5) managed package in my sandbox.
2. And I have a simple App as mentioned in this [wiki](https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-popover):

**HelloWorldApp.app:**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--frame slds-grid--align-center slds-grid--vertical-align-center">

        <div>Note that&nbsp;
            <ui_popover:popover>
            <aura:set attribute="popoverBody">
                <h3 class="slds-section-title">Blah</h3>
                <p class="slds-m-bottom--x-small">Blah<b>any</b> Blah</p>
            </aura:set>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">blah</a>
            </ui_popover:popover>
    &nbsp;blah</div>

    </div>
</aura:application>
```

But it fails with the error:[image]

Screenshots showing it is properly installed in my sandbox and I am not crazy :) [image][image]

**Notes:**

1. I am referencing the component by prefixing the namespace of the
   component as mentioned in [their](https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-popover) documentation
2. Even tried uninstalling and re-installing but still same result.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sandbox Orgs using Summer 17 may have known issues affecting managed packages:

View this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173860/package-installs-with-lightning-components-failing-in-summer-2017-orgs) and this [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008jMrQAI&title=package-install-fails-with-error-no-controller-named-js-xxxxxx-found-or-we-couldn-t-retrieve-the-design-time-component-information-for-component)

Additionally, as a best practice, it is recommended to create a lightning component for re-usability, maintainability, and better performance:

popovertest.cmp

```
<aura:component access="global" >
        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--frame slds-grid--align-center slds-grid--vertical-align-center">

        <div>Note that&nbsp;
            <ui_popover:popover>
            <aura:set attribute="popoverBody">
                <h3 class="slds-section-title">Blah</h3>
                <p class="slds-m-bottom--x-small">Blah<b>any</b> Blah</p>
            </aura:set>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">blah</a>
            </ui_popover:popover>
    &nbsp;blah</div>

    </div>
</aura:component>
```

and then creating the app and reference the component:

popovertest.app

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:popovertest />
</aura:application>
```

[image]

However this may not be the cause of the issue.

Note:
I also copy pasted the code in an app and it works using a dev org on spring 17. This only seems to be affecting Sandbox orgs on Summer 17 as described in the above posted links. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It is weird. I did the same thing in my developer edition org and it is working fine. Not sure why it is happening in my sandbox. Do you think it is because of the version mismatch or something like that??

Comment: did you try creating a component and then referencing the component in an app? (if yes, do you get the same error?)

Comment: ah, one more thing, i believe your sandbox is using summer 17, and the devorg is still on spring 17, correct??

Comment: @javanoob, please view updated post

Comment: You know what, I created a test component as you mentioned and then my app saved fine and then I deleted the test component and it is still working. Not sure why this crazy workaround :) But it solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Oh =) , glad it helped!